# Android source error

Tags: android, python-2.7, tesseract

I am trying to make an Android OCR app using Tesseract. I have followed the instructions given in the following tutorial:
[http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract)

I have been able to successfully build the code using ndk-build. 
But when I run the

```
android update project --PATH
```

after setting the path using

```
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 21, in <module>
    os.execvp("python3", [sys.argv[0]] + sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 344, in execvp
    _execvpe(file, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 380, in _execvpe
    func(fullname, *argrest)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I googled the error and found the following solution:
[Android Source problem](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=121665)

I changed the path location to

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

as suggested in the second link but I got the error: android: command not found

I tried installing the latest version of python, but it gives the same error as above.

I am at a total loss in figuring out what this error is.

Can you please explain what it means and how I can get rid of it?

---

Still getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 21, in <module>
    os.execvp("python3", [sys.argv[0]] + sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 344, in execvp
    _execvpe(file, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 380, in _execvpe
    func(fullname, *argrest)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Please help me figure out what this means and how to overcome it.

Answer (score 0):

After your change, your `$PATH` environment variable doesn't contain the Android SDK path anymore, thus your shell is unable to find the `android` command.
You first want to add the Android SDK path back to your $PATH variable.
In your console type:

`export PATH="$PATH:/path_to_the_Android_SDK/tools/"`

Your first try to change $PATH seems to have overwritten it, instead of appending something to it. Note that `$PATH:` must be included if you add any directories via `export`.

`export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"` should do the trick, assuming that `$ANDROID_HOME` is set. `$ANDROID_HOME` should equal the path to your Android SDK, you should see the platform-tools directory in it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying.
I appended the path for the platform-tools in the android sdk as you suggested, but I still get the other error : 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 21, in <module>
    os.execvp("python3", [sys.argv[0]] + sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 344, in execvp
    _execvpe(file, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 380, in _execvpe
    func(fullname, *argrest)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory


Please help me figure out what this means and how to overcome it.